# Javascript file download not working on IE6 and IE7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have the following code

```
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
```

Opens the new window using the following line of code

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Download", string.Format("window.open('{0}', target = 'new');", downloadURL), true);
```

This works on IE8 however doesn't work on IE6 and IE7

anyidea what might be wrong here?

Comment: What JavaScript commands does this result in?

Comment: window.open and the window is closing. so I don't have the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll most likely get a script error

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Download", string.Format("window.open('{0}', target = 'new');", "http://example.com"), true);
```

should render the javascript:

```
window.open('http://example.com', target = 'new');
```

In the above script, the target variable is undefined. If you wanted the link to open in a new window, try:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Download", string.Format("window.open('{0}', '_blank');", downloadURL), true);
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28VS.85%29.aspx) for a list of the available parameters to the window.open function